# Assigning bucket label to value in new column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bucket

I have a table of one column Precipitation levels in Germany called DataStore:

| PRCP |
| --- |
| 5.6 |
| 10.3 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 3.2 |
| 7 |

and I would like to add another column specifying from which range it belongs to.
for example I want to define the ranges 0-5, 5-10, 10+ so my desired outcome would be:

| PRCP | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 5.6 | 2 |
| 10.3 | 3 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 3.2 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us what research you have done, what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT PRCP,
       CASE WHEN PRCP < 5 THEN 1
            WHEN PRCP < 10 THEN 2
            ELSE 3 END AS Label
FROM yourTable;
```